# Properties or Method for Dictionary

Tags: c#

i read some posts about properties vs Method, but I'm not sure, which way is correct for my purpose.

Should I use properties to return the Dictionary with the UserData or should I use a Method, because is a Collection of data and of course exceptions are possible to caused by e.g. missing file

```
class UsersData
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string UserPassWord { get; set; }
}

class Test
{
     public Dictionary<int, UsersData> Users
    {
        get
        {
            return ReadXMLDict(filename);
        }
        private set
        { }
    }

    public string filename { get; set; }



    public Test()
    {
    }

    private Dictionary<int, UsersData> ReadXMLDict(string filename)
    {
        Dictionary<int, UsersData> result;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filename))
        {
            var XDoc = XDocument.Load(filename).Element("UsersTable");
            result = XDoc
           .Descendants("Users")
           .ToDictionary(x => int.Parse(x.Element("UserID").Value),
             (x => new UsersData
             {
                 UserID = int.Parse(x.Element("UserID").Value),
                 UserName = x.Element("UserName").Value,
                 UserPassWord = x.Element("UserPassWord").Value

             }));
            return result;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It really depends on how complicated your program is.  The real question is when you should make a property public or private.  When you have a private property then you must use a method to get the property from another class.  The more complicated an application the more likely there is a coding error that will incorrectly change a property.  So to prevent coding error corrupting data in a complicated application you make a property private.

Answer (score 1):

Properties are syntactic sugar. They're compiled into methods and they work the same way as methods (f.e. in your case `filename` property is compiled into two methods: `get_filename`, `set_filename`).

You can catch exceptions, handle them and many other things inside a setter or getter, because they're methods.

BTW, if getting the data and filling the whole dictionary requires input parameters, you should stay with a method *as is* (no properties!).

In the other hand, if there're many methods that could require a common parameter, maybe it's fine that you define a property to hold that parameter and later use it in some other property or method:

```
public class A
{
     public string Param1 { get; set; }

     public string PropertyA 
     {
          get 
          {
               // Uses "Param1"

               return ...;
          }
     } 

     public void Method1()
     {
          // Uses "Param1" somewhere...
     }

     public void Method2()
     {
          // Uses "Param1" somewhere...
     }

     public void MethodN()
     {
          // Uses "Param1" somewhere...
     }
}
```

Comment: Ok, in my case  i would like to give some other programmers the access to the xml file values. If they need only partly information's or want to work with the values then they should write their on wrapper above my class, means I have only one parameter to handover and this is the filename. If i understood you correct I can go this way instead of a constructor where the file is returned in a dictionary?

Comment: @Shazter I don't catch your argument at all. Do you mean if in your case it would be fine a public **method**?

Comment: I mean is ok to use a property instead of a public method

Comment: @Shazter Absolutely, it depends on the case, this is what I've tried to describe you in my answer. But it's not only *fine* but C# was designed to use *getters* and *setters* to make things cleaner. In other languages, setting a property is done as follows: `obj.setName("matias")`. You prefer `obj.Name = "matias"`, don't you?

Comment: I will prepare my second example, based on method. It's better to describe for me.

Comment: No need anymore for other example. Understood your comment.

Comment: @Shazter I'm glad you got it :) At the end of the day, your question is very broad, but I feel I could summarize an answer with some facts that can assist you in choosing the right solution depending on the use case.